# Upsert in mogoose schema throwse promise has no method 'save'

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I ma using mongoose and I want ot my PersonSchema to add upsert method
Inside PersonSchema.statics I add like

```
  upsert : function(obj, cb) {
    this.findOne({ _id : obj.id }, function(err, person) {
      console.log('inside find one');
      if(person !== null)
        {
          console.log('found person');
          this.update({'pid':obj.pid},obj,{upsert:true}, cb);
        }
        else
        {
            console.log('saving new person');
            var person  = new PersonSchema(obj);
            person.save(obj);
        }
    });
  },
```

obj is dictionary like `{'_id' : '52e03681ecc7426f2c00000b', 'name' : 'Sally'}`
but I get error

```
promise has no method 'save'
```

How to create upsert method in my mongoose schema ?

Answer (score 0):

[Mongoose Schema](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema) does not have a method called save. Couldn't you just use `upsert` with [Model#findOneAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate)? Would also reduce the calls to Mongo.